# IntelliJ Idea: Configuring Artifacts to contain different web.xml and application.properties

Tags: intellij-idea, web.xml

Is there a way with IntelliJ Idea, to create two kinds of artifacts - for **development** and for **production**, which would containt different sets of files.

I would like to be able to put different `application.properties` and `web.xml` to both of them to create different WAR files.

Of course, I could create some ant or maven builds, but to do it with Idea directly would be much more simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create as many artifacts as needed, in the [Artifact settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html) you can configure which files to package and where, so it's possible to use files from different locations.